# How to translate or change the name of the page 'Contact Us' from the tab name in browser on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, contact-us

I tried to find the page in backend from content -> Pages, but the contact us page is not there.

I also find some answers for Magento 1, that you have to edit this file and change the name from here

```
/app/design/frontend/tm_themes/theme_number/layout/local.xml
```

But on Magento 2 I can't find this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this XML in your theme folder:

> your_theme_root/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Your new contact page title</title>
    </head>
</page>
```

Don't forget clear cache.
Message me if you will have any issues.

Comment: It's working this way!

Answer (score 1):

Both Magento1 and Magento2, "**`Contact Us`**" `pages does not a CMS page.`***it is Manage from a Module.***

If you want then you

You can should do below process:

Create `{Your_LanagaugeCode}.csv` at if not exits

> magento2/app/design/frontend/{themevendorname}/{Themename}/i18n/

Then add below code at this csv file

```
"Contact Us", "YOur_repectWord"
```

***Then  do Cache flush and do the static content deploy.***

**Source:**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Comment: It's not working, your method only translate the page title, but not the title from the tab on browser

Answer (score 0):

Exist some bugs with translate Title  of  Page :)

for translate, 
need add Phraze to translate/locale file.

in your theme - **i18n/de_DE.csv** 
add following - *"Contact Us","Kontaktieren Sie uns"*

and clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these answers worked for me (using Magento 2.1). The title wasn't correctly translated and was just printed in raw English.

However, I've found this solution on another website and it worked fine.

Just add this piece of code in the page Block class you want to translate :

```
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Inventory'));
}
```

The i18n translation file has to be set. Here is an example for the French file "i18n/fr_FR.csv" :

```
"Inventory","Inventaire"
```

My source : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5231#issuecomment-385248982